# WPF model-bound menu with different ItemContainerStyle at top level and other levels

Tags: wpf, xaml, hierarchicaldatatemplate

I am attempting to construct a dynamic WPF menu with different appearance for the top level items and the subsequent level items.  In particular, I would like my top level items to display a 32 pixel square image on top of the menu caption, and the subsequent items to display a 16 pixel image in the regular Icon location.  (I posted a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27489453/wpf-menu-how-to-use-a-different-template-for-top-level-items/27489786#27489786) some days ago, that one was using templates instead of styles).

The XAML code below produces a menu with the following characteristics:

. All menu items bind to and display the 32 pixel icon, leading me to believe that only the second ItemContainerStyle is being used (the one *not* in the Resources section).

. The Command and CommandParameter properties bind correctly; when I click a menu item the command is executed.

. The Name property is *not* bound correctly, all Headers are empty strings.  No binding errors are generated for this property in the Output window.

. The template information given in the Grid (which is supposed to apply to the top-level items) is never rendered.

Based on [this example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.hierarchicaldatatemplate.itemcontainerstyle%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) I believe that part of the problem may be that I have to move my Resources higher in the XAML tree, to the WrapPanel.  When I do this, however, the StaticResources cannot be located in the menu.

How can I modify my menu to apply different styles (or templates -- I'm not picky!) to the top-level items and the other items?

```
<WrapPanel Height="Auto">
    <Menu ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.EventMenu.TopLevel, ElementName=UserControl}">
        <Menu.Resources>
            <Image x:Key="MenuIconResource16" Height="16" Width="16" Source="{Binding Icon16}" x:Shared="False" />
            <Image x:Key="MenuIconResource32" Height="32" Width="32" Source="{Binding Icon32}" x:Shared="False" />
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="SubItemStyle" ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
                        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="true"/>
                        <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding Command}" />
                        <Setter Property="CommandParameter" Value="{Binding EventType}"/>
                        <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Name}"/>
                        <Setter Property="Icon" Value="{StaticResource MenuIconResource16}"/>
                        <!--<Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Children}"/>-->
                    </Style>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemContainerStyle>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </Menu.Resources>
        <Menu.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="true"/>
                    <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding Command}" />
                    <Setter Property="CommandParameter" Value="{Binding EventType}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Name}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Icon" Value="{StaticResource MenuIconResource32}"/>
                    <!--<Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Children}"/>-->
                    <Setter Property="ItemTemplate" Value="{StaticResource SubItemStyle}"></Setter>
                </Style>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Image Grid.Row="0" Width="32" Height="32" VerticalAlignment="Center" Source="{Binding Icon32}"/>
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
            </Grid>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </Menu.ItemTemplate>
    </Menu>
</WrapPanel>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to have confused the `ItemContainerStyle`, which is a `Style` with a `DataTemplate` that could be used in the `ItemTemplate` property. The former is the `Style` for the *container*, or in your case the `MenuItem`, whereas the actual data items should be defined with a `DataTemplate`.

You could achieve your requirements just using `DataTemplate`s and a [`DataTemplateSelector`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datatemplateselector(v=vs.110).aspx), ignoring the  `ItemContainerStyle` for now. This method would require you to declare one `DataTemplate` for the normal items and another for each variation that you want. You would then use the `DataTemplateSelector.SelectTemplate` method to decide which `DataTemplate` to apply to each `MenuItem`.

This example is taken from the linked page on MSDN and demonstrates how you can use the `DataTemplateSelector`:

```
public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
{
    FrameworkElement element = container as FrameworkElement;

    if (element != null && item != null && item is Task)
    {
        Task taskitem = item as Task;

        if (taskitem.Priority == 1)
            return
                element.FindResource("importantTaskTemplate") as DataTemplate;
        else 
            return
                element.FindResource("myTaskTemplate") as DataTemplate;
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Sheridan.  This code goes in the code-behind, correct?  Anyway to accomplish it without code-behind (which is frowned on by this client)?  Also, where do I have to define those templates in order for them to be found by `FindResource()`?

Comment: And yes -- I'm quite confused between Styles and Templates in general.  I tried reading http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc295273.aspx but it pre-supposes more knowledge of WPF than I have.  Any recommendation for a "Styles and Templates for WPF-Dummies" greatly appreciated.

Comment: *This code goes in the code-behind, correct?*... nope, it goes in it's own class that extends the `DataTemplateSelector` class... see the linked page for further help. You can use the [`Application.FindResource` Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.findresource(v=vs.110).aspx) and put your `DataTemplate`s in the `App.xaml Resources` section.

Comment: @LarryLustig You can declare the data template selector as a resource in your XAML http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datatemplateselector%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Try looking at the [Styling and Templating](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745683(v=vs.110).aspx) and maybe [Control Authoring Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745025(v=vs.110).aspx) pages on MSDN for some background info.

Comment: Thank you.  I did get this working, although I'm not certain why one specific part (setting the Icon property's style) works correctly.  That question (and my working code) can be seen here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27746792/why-does-my-menuitem-have-an-icon-when-i-have-overridden-the-datatemplate