# Why does my MenuItem have an Icon when I have overridden the DataTemplate?

Tags: wpf, xaml, datatrigger

I have successfully implement a WPF menu where the top-level items are drawn as large buttons and the lower level items are drawn as standard menu items (see my previous questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27551668/wpf-model-bound-menu-with-different-itemcontainerstyle-at-top-level-and-other-le) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27489453/wpf-menu-how-to-use-a-different-template-for-top-level-items)).

In my original attempt at this my lower-level item template (`SubItemTemplate` in the example below) contained an image and a textblock.  The result was something that looked like a normal menu item with an empty Icon area and the image next to the text in the text part of the menu item.  I was not expecting to see the icon area in the visual display since I thought that the entire visual display would be determined by the contents of my template.  The top-level template (`TopLevelItemTemplate`) does not have any empty icon area visible.

When I removed my image from teh lower-level template and replaced it with a style-setter for the Icon property, I got the display that I wanted.

I do not understand how and why the Icon property exists on my lower-level item DataTemplate.

Here's my code.  The property `HasParent` is used to distinguish menu items that are not top-level (that is, the ones that are drawn with the `SubItemTemplate`).  The section I don't understand is the DataTrigger.

Why is there an Icon property available inside that trigger?

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Image x:Key="MenuIconResource16" Height="16" Width="16" Source="{Binding Icon32}" x:Shared="False" />

    <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="TopLevelItemTemplate" ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
        <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Orientation="Vertical">
            <Image Width="32" Height="32" VerticalAlignment="Center" Source="{Binding Icon32}" ToolTip="{Binding UserHint}" />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="SubItemTemplate" ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>

<WrapPanel Height="Auto">
   <Menu ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.EventMenu.TopLevel, ElementName=UserControl}" ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource MenuItemTemplateSelector}">
       <Menu.ItemContainerStyle>
           <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
               <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding Command}" />
               <Setter Property="CommandParameter" Value="{Binding EventType}"/>
               <Style.Triggers>
                   <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding HasParent}" Value="true">
                       <Setter Property="Icon" Value="{StaticResource MenuIconResource16}"/>
                   </DataTrigger>
               </Style.Triggers>
           </Style>
       </Menu.ItemContainerStyle>
   </Menu>
</WrapPanel>
```

Comment: Everything that you put in `DataTemplate` will be used in `MenuItem.Content` when `MenuItem` wrapper is created. So when you put in `DataTemplate` is becomes `Content` and when you set it in `Style` you set `Icon` property of `MenuItem` wrapper, and `DataTemplate` provides content. If you want to change how `MenuItem` is displayed you would have to change `MenuItem.Template`, which is by default different for top level and sub menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I thought that the entire visual display would be determined by the contents of my template.

@dkozl noted the difference between `DataTemplate` and `Template` -- that is the important distinction.  A data template is a XAML fragment that the owning control uses as part of the overall control, which may or may not include other (customizable or hard-coded) visual elements, and/or other data templates.  The control template is where this visual structure of the control is defined.  If you set/override a control template, then your expectation of not seeing any other visual content, will hold true.

> The top-level template (`TopLevelItemTemplate`) does not have any empty icon area visible.

The other thing to note here is that the default style for `Menu` defines multiple control templates for its `MenuItems`.  These templates are applied depending on the role "TopLevelHeader", "TopLevelItem", "SubmenuHeader", and "SubmenuItem".  So you will see different behavior for these different menu items.  Take a look at the [default styles/templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752296%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which should be illuminating (although they are kind of complex).

> Why is there an Icon property available inside that trigger?

A style trigger has the capability of modifying any dependency property of the control it is applied to.  Since the style trigger in question is being applied to the `MenuItem` control, it can modify the [`Icon` dependency property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.menuitem.icon(v=vs.110).aspx), which is owned by that control.

Comment: Thanks!  There seem to be complexities nested in the complexities of WPF.  Question: I had to introduce a property (`HasParent`) which is used only to trigger the style (and in the DataTemplateSelector that chooses between the two templates).  Is there any way I can get access to the role you described (`TopLevelItem`, etc) so that I can remove that otherwise needless property from my model?

Comment: @LarryLustig not sure I understood, but you should be able to access the `Role` property from a ControlTemplate using `Binding RelativeSource=TemplatedParent,Path=Role`, and from a DataTemplate inside the control using `Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=MenuItem},Path=Role`.